# What do I have to change that Jupyter shows columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I just want to import this csv file. It can read it but somehow it doesn't create columns. Does anyone know why?

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

songs_data = pd.read_csv('../datasets/spotify-top50.csv', encoding='latin-1')
songs_data.head(n=10)
```

Result that I see in Jupyter:

[image]

P.S.: I'm kinda new to Jupyter and programming, but after all I found it should work properly. I don't know why it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

To properly load a csv file you should specify some parameters. for example in you case you need to specify quotechar:

```
df = pd.read_csv('../datasets/spotify-top50.csv',quotechar='"',sep=',', encoding='latin-1')
df.head(10)
```

If you still have a problem you should have a look at your CSV file again and also pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), so that you can set parameters to match with your CSV file structure.